# Best practices for c-style ifdef usage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, macros, c-preprocessor

When using C/C++ (or, most languages that use the C preprocessor), I find that a very common pattern is to use macros to separate 'builds' or 'environments' (correct me if that is not as frequent as I believe).

For example:

Assume the macros `__DEV__` and `__PROD__` are defined respectively in
the development and production builds of a C project.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    #ifdef __DEV__
      printf("argc: %d\n", argc);

      for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
          printf("argv[%d]: %s", i, argv[i]);
      }
    #endif
    #ifdef __PROD__
      printf("Hello world!");
    #endif

    printf("exiting...");
}
```

The main benifit I see here is, outside of being able to maintain multiple builds inline, there is exactly no runtime overhead.

Because transpilers are so frequently used (at least on the backend) in Javascript, is there a similar pattern that is widely used? (or recognized to be semi-idiomatic)

As far as I'm aware, the only usage of such a pattern is through the following:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  database.connect(/* */);

  // ...
}
```

Though the overhead is small, it is always there, and moreover, it feels odd to ship development code with production. Building a project in the c-style way would physically remove that.

Comment: That's a compile-time feature and javascript generally isn't compiled. However there are systems that do packaging and re-arrangement for Javascript. For example, node.js with webpack and [ifdef-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifdef-loader).

Comment: Side note: `Assume the macros __DEV__ and __PROD__` Macros starting with double `__` are reserved for compiler. Do not use such macros in your C code.

Comment: @KamilCuk I stray from them for all purposes but messing with compiler and pre-compiler stuff. It's almost always to hide implementation in C header files when dancing with __attribute__(()) macros and stuff on embedded systems. Using C++ I almost never do outside of those listed for the environment (probably a bad habit, but I see it a lot (especially with old ISO haters)). In terms of this question, I realized the real problem with the approach is trying to use #ifdef statements at all instead of using more readable if statements and relying on constant folding.